# How to count the number of occurrence in 4 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a T-SQL query to do in the most efficient way as possible.

Here is an example of my table:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x, y | z | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | x | NULL | NULL | y |
| 3 | y | z | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | a | NULL | b | x |

Now, I need to do a query to classify my best matching records. Let's say that I need to take the top 3 records that match the more of the values 'x' & 'y' (it could be more than 2 values) into the columns B, C, D, E

| A | NumberOfMatches | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Because Column B contains x, y |
| 2 | 2 | Because Column B contains x & Column E contains y |
| 3 | 1 | Because Column B contains y |
| 4 | 1 | Because Column E contains x |

Could you help me to find a good way to do this query?

Comment: Looks like you need to fix your design first; column `B` contains delimited data.

Comment: *"I have a sql query to do in the most efficient way as possible."* Can you show us said query? If it's already efficient, what is your question here? What about your query isn't working?

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are trying to do here. This needs some details to be answerable.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend that you change how your data is stored, storing delimited strings to record multiple values is a recipe for disaster. If you have a one to many relationship use a child table with a foreign key to the main table. There is very rarely a reason to store delimited data like this, and when you have to query it and manipulate it you realise why it is not advised.

Assuming that each of your columns are the same and can hold many values, you'll need to split all of them, which you can do using this:

```
SELECT  t.A, upvt.Col, Value = TRIM(ss.value)
FROM    #T AS t
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('B', t.B), ('C', t.C), ('D', t.D), ('E', t.E)) upvt (Col, Value)
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(upvt.Value, ',') AS ss;
```

Which gives:

| A | Col | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | x |
| 1 | B | y |
| 1 | C | z |
| 2 | B | x |
| 2 | E | y |
| 3 | B | y |
| 3 | C | z |
| 4 | B | a |
| 4 | D | b |
| 4 | E | x |

With this normalised data, you can then just do a simple `WHERE Value IN ('x', 'y')` along with `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)`:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T ', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T ;

CREATE TABLE #T (A INT, B VARCHAR(4), C VARCHAR(4), D VARCHAR(4), E VARCHAR(4));

INSERT #T(A, B, C, D, E)
VALUES
    (1, 'x, y', 'z', NULL, NULL),
    (2, 'x', NULL, NULL, 'y'),
    (3, 'y', 'z', NULL, NULL),
    (4, 'a', NULL, 'b', 'x');

SELECT  t.A, NumberOfMatches = COUNT(*)
FROM    #T AS t
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES (t.B), (t.C), (t.D), (t.E)) upvt (Value)
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(upvt.Value, ',') AS ss
WHERE   TRIM(ss.value) IN ('x', 'y')
GROUP BY t.A
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, t.A;
```

Comment: Hello,
As my data model is CMS based no I cannot change my model this is how the CMS store it. your proposal could be interesting. I will investigate the performance of this query.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't normalize the model you can use this query to get your expected result:

```
select a, count(*) numberOfMatches,
concat('Because column ', string_agg(columnName, ', ')) AS comment
from (
    select a, columnName, trim(value) targetValue from (
        select a, columnName, value result
        from tbl unpivot (value for columnName in ([B], [C], [D], [E])) up
    ) t 
    outer apply string_split(result,',') 
) r 
where targetValue in ('x','y')
group by a

-- Result
/*
a   numberOfMatches comment
1   2               Because column B, B
2   2               Because column B, E
3   1               Because column B
4   1               Because column E
*/
```

**Update**

You can use [this custom function](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/string_split-function-for-sql-2012-and-above) in order to implement string_split in SQL Server prior versions.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[STRING_SPLIT]','IF') IS NULL BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[STRING_SPLIT] () RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN SELECT 1 X') 
END
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[STRING_SPLIT]
(
    @string    nvarchar(MAX), 
    @separator nvarchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS RETURN
   WITH X(N) AS (SELECT 'Table1' FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) T(C)),
        Y(N) AS (SELECT 'Table2' FROM X A1, X A2, X A3, X A4, X A5, X A6, X A7, X A8) , -- Up to 16^8 = 4 billion
        T(N) AS (SELECT TOP(ISNULL(LEN(@string),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 N FROM Y),
        Delim(Pos) AS (SELECT t.N FROM T WHERE (SUBSTRING(@string, t.N, LEN(@separator+'x')-1) LIKE @separator OR t.N = 0)),
        Separated(value) AS (SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, d.Pos + LEN(@separator+'x')-1, LEAD(d.Pos,1,2147483647) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - d.Pos - LEN(@separator)) 
                               FROM Delim d
                              WHERE @string IS NOT NULL)
       SELECT s.value
         FROM Separated s
        WHERE s.value <> @separator
GO
```

**Update 2**

Just 1 if the field has **x,y** at the same time:

```
select a, count(distinct columnName) numberOfMatches,
concat('Because column ', string_agg(columnName, ', ')) AS comment
from (
    select a, columnName, trim(value) targetValue from (
        select a, columnName, value result
        from tbl unpivot (value for columnName in ([B], [C], [D], [E])) up
    ) t 
    outer apply string_split(result,',') 
) r 
where targetValue in ('x','y')
group by a


/* another alternative */

select a, count(*) numberOfMatches,
concat('Because column ', string_agg(columnName, ', ')) AS comment
from (
    select a, columnName, value targetValue
    from tbl unpivot (value for columnName in ([B], [C], [D], [E])) up
) t 
where targetValue like '%x%' or targetValue like '%y%'
group by a

-- Result
/*
a   numberOfMatches comment
1   1               Because column B
2   2               Because column B, E
3   1               Because column B
4   1               Because column E
*/
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you I didn't knew the unpivot stuffs.
But the `outer apply string_split(result,',') `stuff didn't work apparently

Comment: You need SQL Server 2016+ to use this function.

Comment: @Kapoue check the update.

Comment: thanks for this update but I am in the version 150 of SQL so > 2016 and even with this additional function I still have two rows: 1 | B | x, y but I guess that I should have one row with x and one with y right?

Comment: If your version is 15 that means you have a database with a lower compatibility level. That's why you cannot use string_split function

Comment: @Kapoue check the new update.